Add Blob to Spreadsheet Cell via Quip Automation API as an Image
I am trying to use the automation api to create a blob of an image file and then add the image to a cell within a spreadsheet.
The documentation specifies that AddBlobToThread API Returns a url that may be used in the content field of Edit Document requests and an id that may be used in the attachment field of Add a Message.
https://quip.com/dev/automation/documentation/current#operation/addBlobToThread
However when I attempt to add it as content like this string <img src='/blob/SMB9AAapurq/reSUi8F9UHcP9El8WRMKHw' /> I get a 500 Inernal Server Error response from the Edit a Document Quip API. I have tried constructing a full url to the blob, and tried using a formula instead =IMAGE(src). But nothing works.
Is there a way to programmatically update a spreadsheet with an image that will render?
